# Question text of unknown origin

Tags: bug, editor

When I view [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018730/fprintf-with-string-argument), it currently looks like this:

[image: question in question]
But when I click edit, this is the full text of the question:

```
In order to creation a formatted file, I want to utilize `fprintf`. it
must get `char*` but I have several string variables. Can anyone help
me, please?
Thanks
```

I also looked in the history, and don't see "Dear all" anywhere. Where is that first line coming from?

Comment: Answered on Meta.SE: [Edit source differs from question view, or are we each other's friends now?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123981)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [feature was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989) after that post was created that attempts to automatically strip some of the more common salutations from post bodies as they are just clutter in a post. Older posts were not automatically updated, but an attempt at editing with the feature implemented now will remove that text from the body.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I closed the question already, but I'll accept your answer once it lets me.

Comment: Come to think of it, it's still odd that it was stripped from the history.

Comment: @Brian I don't believe the revision history is cached at all, so it probably gets run through the filter to remove it. The post body displayed on the main question page is only rendered when its updated, and cached for life or until it gets updated again.