# Question text shown is different when editing

Tags: bug

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191653/i-want-to-restore-the-database-with-a-different-schema) looks like this:

[image]

I went to edit out the "Dear All", but it looks like someone else got there first:

[image]

Some kind of caching issue?

Comment: Also: [*Question text of unknown origin*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284703/2751851) -- a dupl*cate mentioning this exact salutation.

Comment: Wow. Talk about surprising behaviour. Why not just update the old questions?